Global existence for quadratic ODE
It is known systems of ODEs with a locally Lipschitz vector field can only have local existence results, as the solutions may blow up in finite time. I wonder if anything can be said on selected quadratic problem, for instance the following one
$$
x’ = xy, \qquad y’ = y^2 - x- x^2
$$
In which possibly the term $-x$ can be multiplied by a constant, if need be.
Do you think global existence can be rescued in any way?

Your example has solutions that blow up in finite time, namely
$$ x = 0, \ y = \frac{1}{c-t}$$
On the other hand, trajectories that start out with $x \ne 0$ are on the level curves of
$$F(x, y) = \frac{y^2}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x} + 2 \ln |x|
$$
In the left half-plane these are closed curves giving periodic solutions.  In the right half-plane they start and end at the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ (corresponding to $t \to -\infty$ and $t \to +\infty$).  In both cases we have global existence.

thanks, I guess this can also be extended to the case where the vectorfields are translated by a constant
